# close pop newslettr form when clicked outside black backround?

Tags: javascript, email, bigcommerce

I have a email newsletter popup form in my website.I want to close email newsletter window when clicked anywhere outside. How can i achieve this with some java script code?

http://wristology.mybigcommerce.com/

Note : Please use private browser window for showing pop up every time.

Answer (score 0):

Attach a click handler to the `document` object when the pop up opens. On click, hide the pop up then detach the event handler.